# php cannot open text file on network drive

Tags: php, network-drive, httpbackend

I have written a PHP script to create a text file on a network drive in 'write' mode, but for some reason, the text file cannot be created. Here's the original script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$myfile = fopen("Z:\\User\\WebInput\\inputParams.txt", "w") or die("Unable 
to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, "Attr\tValue".PHP_EOL);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

The error message I got is:

> Warning: fopen(Z:\User\WebInput\inputParams.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

I have set the folder 'WebInput' permission so that everyone can read and write to it, but it still says no such directory. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried w+ ?

Comment: Forgot link to [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Why do you have double slashes everywhere? Should it not be `fopen("Z:\User\WebInput\inputParams.txt", "w")`?

Comment: @Frits : true, but @LingpinZeng is also asking how to `create` a file, and 'w' won't be enough

Comment: I agree @OldPadawan - perhaps I should have added that into my comment, however I didn't want to parrot what you said :)

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver or from the command line?

Comment: @Frits — ``\`` is an escape character in a PHP string literal.

Comment: @Quentin __*facepalm*__. Ofcourse - it seems I am need of some more coffee.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I'm running this on a webserver. Basically I have written a html script that will pass http request to another php script once the user fills out some forms and clicks a button. The php script will get those parameters passed from the html and write them to a network drive. At this point, the php script can write the parameters to a local directory, like C:\\Users\\inputParams.txt, but for some reason, it cannot write the data to a shared network drive. Do you know why?

Comment: @AbraCadaver If I run the php script alone from command line, it works fine writing the data to the shared network drive. The problem arises when I try to use the html script to call php to write the user parameters into a text file in the shared network drive. Do you have any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: The system user that runs the webserver does not have that drive mapped.